# Representations of $GL_n(F_q)$ over a finite field

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings, general-linear-group

If $F_q$ denotes a finite field of characteristic $p,$ then I want to learn about the representations of $G = GL_n(F_q)$ over a finite field $K$ such that $char(K) \ \nmid |G|.$ Any reference suggestion would be of great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any finite field, or a sufficiently large finite field? In the former case, good luck. In the latter case, this is the same as characteristic $0$. The character table of $GL_n(q)$ is known algorithmically (a 1955 paper of Green gives the answer, but unless you are a research mathematician, don't expect to understand it).

Comment: What does a sufficiently large finite field stand for?

Comment: So that all irreducible modules are absolutely irreducible. It's so that there are enough roots of unity in your field that the character values appear in $K$. In fields of positive characteristic, the representation can be defined over $K$ if and only if its character can. (This is false for characteristic $0$.) So, for example, the cyclic group of order $4$ has different representations depending on whether a $4$th root of 1 is in $K$ or not.

Comment: I don't mean any offence by this, but if you didn't know what I meant by sufficiently large finite field, it is highly unlikely you'll be able to understand Green's paper. But you never know.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I had an idea but was not aware of the terminology though. I hope the reference you are mentioning is "THE CHARACTERS OF THE FINITE GENERAL LINEAR GROUPS" by J.A. Green.

Comment: Yes. Have a look. It uses Jordan decomposition and a recursion to get all of the characters, together with standard symmetric group representation theory to obtain a character degree formula.

Comment: Sure. But if the field is not sufficiently large, then in that case do we have some information?

Comment: You would need the fields of values of all of the characters, which is computable from Green's paper. Then you would need the splitting of all of the irrationalities in the table over whichever finite fields you are interested in. In theory it can be done.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I feel that all the characters of GLn(F) have been given in the paper by Green. But are all of the corresponding representations also known?

Comment: You actually want matrices? No. There is likely no source for matrices for all representations of any sufficiently complicated group. Characters are much, *much* easier than getting pairs of matrices that generate the group. I don't know what you want to do with the matrices, but I would recommend finding some other way to do it!

Comment: I wanted to know the explicit irreducible representation corresponding to which those irreducible characters are coming, I mean is it doable for special linear groups of small orders, say SL_3(F_3)? Sorry if my question is too basic, actually I have started learning all this very recently.

Comment: For tiny groups it might be feasible, like $\mathrm SL_3(3)$. Groups where the representations have degree less than about 1000 are possible, although it depends on the group and how one can actually make them. This is all via computer, nobody in their right mind writes down representations of dimension more than about 5 unless they have a nice form.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Actually, I didnt mean to write matrices. I was talking about using results like those of doubly transitive action, the induced characters and say from clifford thoery to obtain information about all the representations of a particular small group (whose degrees I already know through character tables). In case of symmetric groups, using concept of Specht modules, such information is already there. It would be very nice of you if you can let me know whether such complete information is already there for some other groups too?

Comment: The advantage with $S_n$ is that you have a very nice parametrization of the conjugacy classes by partitions and that is why the representation theory is so nice. But you don't have such a nice description in general for other groups. If you take specially the $GL_r(\mathbf{F}_q)$, then you can parametrize the conjugacy classes by its rational normal forms which roughly correspond to the different maximal tori in $GL_r$.. And some of these tori (the split ones) give raise to nice representations via parabolic induction, but not all of them.